# JS Promise resolve object

Tags: javascript, object, promise, strapi

The following method verifies JWT and returns id and expiration.

```
verify(token, secret = "jwtSecret") {
    console.log("verify jwt: ", secret);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        jwt.verify(
            token,
            _.get(strapi.plugins, ['users-permissions', 'config', secret]),
            {},
            function (err, tokenPayload = {}) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(new Error('Invalid token.'));
                }
                console.log(tokenPayload);
                resolve(tokenPayload);
            }
        );
    });
},
```

When I call verify, I am expecting to return the following object

```
Promise { { id: 77, iat: 1593603153, exp: 1596195153 } }
```

But I am unable to access the id of the object.

When I am doing `console.log("user id: ", payload.id)`, the payload.id is showing up as **undefined** in console.

```
async refreshToken(ctx) {
    const { token } = ctx.request.body;
    const payload = strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.verify(token, "jwtRefreshSec");
    console.log("auth: ", payload); // this log ->  Promise { { id: 77, iat: 1593603153, exp: 1596195153 } } 
    console.log("user id: ", payload.id); // this log -> undefined
    return data;

},
```

Comment: You may need to await the result of the promise: `const payload = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.verify(token, "jwtRefreshSec");`

Comment: Why did you add the `async` modifier before `refreshToken`? `payload` is a `Promise()`, so have you read how to work with `Promise`s?

Comment: @Andreas this is perfectly valid with the ES2017 async/await

Comment: @FrostyZombi3 I know, but I want to know from OP why it's there

Comment: @FrostyZombi3 this works
`const payload = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.verify(token, "jwtRefreshSec");` Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Andreas* suggested, it would be advisable to review how promises work.

From MDN:

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created.

In your first case (`console.log("auth: ", payload);`), the `console.log` function knows that it should print the value of the promise once it receives it.

In the 2nd case, (`console.log("user id: ", payload.id);`), the promise hasn't resolved by the time you try access the id property of the result.

There's 2 ways to resolve this issue.

## Method 1: Using then

```
refreshToken(ctx) {
    const { token } = ctx.request.body;
    const payload = strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.verify(token, "jwtRefreshSec")
        .then(payload => {
            console.log("auth: ", payload); // this log ->  { id: 77, iat: 1593603153, exp: 1596195153 }
            console.log("user id: ", payload.id); // this log -> 77
            return data;
        });
   
},
```

## Method 2: ES2017 Aysnc/Await

```
async refreshToken(ctx) {
    const { token } = ctx.request.body;
    const payload = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.verify(token, "jwtRefreshSec");
    // Will wait for promise to resolve before continuing with await above
    console.log("auth: ", payload); // this log ->  { id: 77, iat: 1593603153, exp: 1596195153 }
    console.log("user id: ", payload.id); // this log -> 77
    return data;

},
```